# Python 3.9: importlib exec_module() does not execute module

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

Given the following Python module layout:

```
app/
├── drivers
│   ├── mydriver
│   │   ├── driver.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

I am trying to dynamically import the "mydriver" module in main.py:

```
import os
import importlib

driver_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'drivers')

loader_details = (
    importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader,
    importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
)

finder = importlib.machinery.FileFinder(driver_dir, loader_details)
spec = finder.find_spec('mydriver')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# The following line produces AttributeError: module 'mydriver' has no attribute 'driver'
driver = getattr(module, 'driver')
```

`drivers/mydriver/__init__.py` contains the following:

```
from . import driver
print("TEST")
```

So the result is the Attribute error as written in the inline comment. The "print()" from `__init__.py` is also not being executed.

Any hints why the module is apparently not being evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't found a root cause, I did find a (not so pretty) workaround. For some reason, the module can not be executed if it was found using the FileFinder. It does however execute if I do the following:

```
sys.path.insert(0, driver_dir)
spec = importlib.util.find_spec('mydriver')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

So in short, I don't know what Python wants from a Finder to also execute modules, not just files. Well, at least I have working code for now...